# EventListeners and custom gui components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, actionlistener

I have a SWING GUI class that instantiates a custom JPanel for a portion of the display. This custom class has buttons and textfields and etc. My GUI class that owns the custom JPanel also has a controller class that handles the modification of the my data models. How can I pass actions from the custom panel to it's owner (my gui class) to handle the events?

I've had the thought that perhaps I can add to my constructor of the custom panel a reference to my controller class in the gui so that I can then set it as the actionListener on my buttons. Is this approach advisable? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `View` code (your custom `JPanel`) should have a `Controller` field (or some other way of obtaining your controller class). That way when you receive an action from the user - e.g. a mouse click on a button - you can call `controller.doTheAppropriateAction()`. Either pass the `Controller` in at construction, or use a Javabean setter pattern on it, and set it just after construction in your start-up logic (which sounds like your "GUI class"). I prefer the Javabean pattern, because GUI Editors need no-parameter constructors.

You should register your `View` as a `Listener` to the relevant `Controller` (or `Model`) classes, so that you will automatically be told when anything changes - so you can `repaint()` your `Component`s (or do something more advanced). That will involve setting up your own `interface` (for the `View` to implement) and listener handling logic in the `Controller` (or `Model`).

[Lombok PG](https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/wiki/%40ListenerSupport) takes the boilerplate out of the latter.

`akf` gives an alternative: register your `Controller` as an `ActionListener` to your `View` code. The advantage of that approach is that your `View` code will not be tied to a specific `Controller` - but the disadvantage is that your `Controller` will be tied to your `View` code. I tend to re-use `Controller` code for different UI implementations (e.g. Swing, GWT, JSP) so my `Controller`s and `Model`s are never dependent on any particular `View` or atomic user action.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a reference to your parent GUI as an `ActionListener` to your custom panel.  Your custom panel can then register your `ActionListener`-implementing parent class with all of your buttons, etc.

Your parent class would then get notified on each action.